# How to send an id broughted by json from ajax to a php post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I have this ajax to show a html table, the thing is, i have a method on viewmap.php to show the ubication depending the id you clicked at the table, but i need to send the uid to viewmap.php so the php can search it at the database, and i don't extactly know how to do that

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "editinplace.php?tabla=1"
    })
    //Vector
    .done(function(json)  
    {
        json = $.parseJSON(json)
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
        {   

            $('.editinplace').append
            (

                "<tr><td class='id' value='uid'>"
                +json[i].uid
                +"</td><td>"
                +json[i].name
                +"</td><td>"
                +json[i].ape
                +"</td><td>"
                +json[i].phone
                +"</span></td><td class='editable' data-campo='status'><span>"
                +json[i].status
                +"</span><td>"
                +"<a href='viewmap.php?uid=$uid'>View on map</a>"
                +"</td>"

                );

        }
        //
    });
```

Comment: Use AJAX to send the data, and inside JavaScript `.done()`. PHP executes as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it not the uid you have from your json array?

```
"<a href='viewmap.php?uid="+json[i].uid+"'>View on map</a>"
```

If you want to pull it from php, you'd echo it like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editinplace.php?tabla=1"
})
//Vector
.done(function(json)  
{
    json = $.parseJSON(json)
    for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
    {   
      var uid = "<?php echo $uid; ?>";
        $('.editinplace').append
        (

            "<tr><td class='id' value='uid'>"
            +json[i].uid
            +"</td><td>"
            +json[i].name
            +"</td><td>"
            +json[i].ape
            +"</td><td>"
            +json[i].phone
            +"</span></td><td class='editable' data-campo='status'><span>"
            +json[i].status
            +"</span><td>"
            +"<a href='viewmap.php?uid="+uid+"'>View on map</a>"
            +"</td>"

            );

    }
    //
});
```

Comment: can't put `var` in json output

Comment: i tried this:

         "<a href='viewmap.php?uid='"+json[i].uid+">View on map</a>"

But the uid at the url shows empty:   viewmap.php?uid=

Comment: The single quote is in the wrong place. Should be after the double quote before the anchor close to encompass the url. If it is still blank you should try viewing the json response in the browser dev tools.  "<a href='viewmap.php?uid="+json[i].uid+"'>View on map</a>"

Comment: Fixed the error, nice catch @ShadMickelberry

Answer (score 0):

If you have shorthand PHP echo tags turned on, its simply -

```
"<a href='viewmap.php?uid=<?= $uid ?>'>View on map</a>"#
```

Otherwise its like this with full tags -

```
"<a href='viewmap.php?uid=<?php echo($uid); ?>'>View on map</a>"#
```

Comment: But how can i put the uid into a variable $uid?

Comment: In the PHP script at the other end you just need to get the uid from the GET request by `$uid = $_GET['uid'];`